# JavaScript and CSS not working in my liferay portlet

Tags: javascript, css, jsp, portlet, liferay-6

I have to use some JavaScript and CSS for my portlet. I am using some datable jQuery for sorting and some interactive display, but it's not working.

Can anyone guide me to where I am making a mistake?

This is my directory structure of docroot where my JS and CSS is kept.

[image]

Here is my view.jsp file in which am filling data dynamically.

```
<%@page import="com.video.util.VideoActionUtil"%>
<%@page import="com.video.database.model.Video"%>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"
    import="com.video.database.model.Video.*"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Applying JQuery DataTables plugin in the Java Server application</title>

     <link href="docroot/js/jquery-1.2.6.min.js" type="text/javascript">
        <link href="docroot/css/demo_page.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <link href="docroot/css/demo_table.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <link href="docroot/css/demo_table_jui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <link href="docroot/css/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />
        <link href="docroot/css/jquery-ui-1.7.2.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />
        <script src="docroot/js/query.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="docroot/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#companies").dataTable({
                "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
                "bJQueryUI": true
            });
        });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body id="dt_example">
        <div id="container">

            <div id="demo_jui">
                <table id="companies" class="display">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Company name</th>
                            <th>Address</th>
                            <th>Town</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <% 
                        long l=10154;
                        for(Video c: VideoActionUtil.getAllVideo(l)){ %>
                          <tr>
                            <td><%=c.getTitle()%></td>
                            <td><%=c.getDescription()%></td>
                            <td><%=c.getTypeId()%></td>
                          </tr>
                        <% } %>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Maybe it can't locate the CSS and JavaScript?
I have tried with the path  `href=/css/[filename]`  but this also doesn't work so I have given `docroot/css/ [filename]`.

Thanks and Regards
Bhavik Kama

@ Mr. Barmar

```
 <script src="../js/jquery-1.2.6.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <link href="../css/demo_page.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <link href="../css/demo_table.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <link href="../css/demo_table_jui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <link href="../css/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />
        <link href="../css/jquery-ui-1.7.2.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />
        <script src="../js/query.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="../js/jquery.dataTables.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
```

Comment: thanks for reply,but have tried that.its not working.any other suggestion?

Comment: check generated html, does it point to expected place? can you get css/js files with direct url ?  (like `http://domain.com/css/my.css`) which url of the view.jsp ? it is inside docroot or inside docroot/other_dir/ or other_dir ?

Comment: this is the link i get on my source of html in browser and when am click on that then this is the page with error i got"The page you are trying to view cannot be shown because it uses an invalid or unsupported form of compression."

Comment: my view.jsp is inside docroot/jsps/view.jsp

Comment: That error sounds like there's a problem with your server configuration, it's sending the wrong `Content-Encoding`.

Comment: sorry?i couldn't get you..can you please explain?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@tairi that also we can do.but i got my solution just gave path to the particular **js or css** with the following

```
<script src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/js/jquery-1.2.6.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

for others who have problem like this then just retrieve your `css/js` file with the `<%=request.getContextPath()%>`

thanks all of you.somehow you helped me to achieve this.

Comment: This helped me when I needed to add some images to my portlet.
I created a /img/ folder under docroot and put the pictures there.
I could reference them in my jsps via 
<img alt="Redirecting" src="<%=request.getContextPath() %>/img/ajax-loader.gif" />

Comment: By the way, `<html>` and `<DOCTYPE>` in `view.jsp` of a portlet? that is just not right! And this approach might create problems when using `https`.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of using `<link href="docroot/js/jquery-1.2.6.min.js" type="text/javascript">` , you can use :

```
<link href="/js/jquery-1.2.6.min.js" type="text/javascript">
```

This is the absolute path for your file, the `/` means the `docroot` folder.
Btw, liferay use default loading css and js file which is defined in `docroot\WEB-INF\liferay-portlet.xml` like this:

```
<portlet>
    <portlet-name>Your portlet name</portlet-name>
    <icon>/icon.png</icon>
    <indexer-class>Your portlet class</indexer-class>
    <instanceable>false</instanceable>
    <header-portlet-css>/css/main.css - link to your header css</header-portlet-css>
    <footer-portlet-javascript>/js/main.js - link to your header js</footer-portlet-javascript>
    <css-class-wrapper>DongBat-SLL-DT-portlet</css-class-wrapper>
</portlet>
```

So you can change or include js or css from these file to load for header.

Comment: shall i add more then one css and js? and what does it mean by headed css and header js?

Comment: header css and header js will be called by default to of your portlet, you don't need to include it again

Comment: Sorry?i cant get it!! i am asking that what is the diffrence bewen header css and header js and same with footer js and footer css

Comment: header css to load your default css, header js to load your default javascript to header of your portlet page, and footer css and js is to load at footer. I.E you can add some init js to your header js, and something like $(document).ready(function()) to your footer js. It's optional

Answer (score 2):

As @Taiki indicates In liferay there is a xml descriptor file which allows you to set the css and javascript used in the portlet in either the portal header or footer

liferay-portlet.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE liferay-portlet-app PUBLIC "-//Liferay//DTD Portlet Application 5.2.0//EN"
        "http://www.liferay.com/dtd/liferay-portlet-app_5_2_0.dtd">
<liferay-portlet-app>
    <portlet>
        <portlet-name>PortletName</portlet-name>
        <header-portlet-css>/css/your.css</header-portlet-css>
        <header-portlet-javascript>/js/jquery.js</header-portlet-javascript>
       <footer-portlet-javascript>/js/your.js</footer-portlet-javascript>
    </portlet>

</liferay-portlet-app>
```

If you place this in your WEB-INF adjust the paths accordingly and you are good to go no need to reference the files in your view

Comment: ya..i got it..thnks to u and @Taiki

Answer (score 1):

URLs that do not begin with `/` are interpreted relative to the directory in the URL that references them. So if a page with URL `http://domain.com/docroot/jsps/view.jsp` accesses `docroot/css/something.css`, it will look for `http://domain.com/docroot/jsps/docroot/css/something.css`.

Try using paths like `../css/[filename].css` and `../js/[filename].js`. `../` means to go up one level in the directory hierarchy.

Comment: ya you are right and i have tried that too.but don't know why still not working.please see at the end i have updated my answer as u suggested.but its not working